# Maven create specific ksh with the list of dependencies

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

This is a maven question, not a ksh one.

I am trying to generate dynamically with maven a ksh script to launch a java application in production environment.

The aim of the script is to setup the classpath of the java application and launch it.

The ksh at end should be like that:

```
#!/bin/ksh
launchbatch() {
   $JRE_HOME/bin/java -cp $BATCH_CLASSPATH $PRG_NAME
}

setclasspath() {
    BATCH_CLASSPATH=$BATCH_PROPERTIES/
    BATCH_CLASSPATH="$BATCH_CLASSPATH:$BATCH_LIB/activation-1.1.jar"
    BATCH_CLASSPATH="$BATCH_CLASSPATH:$BATCH_LIB/annotations-1.0.0.jar"
    BATCH_CLASSPATH="$BATCH_CLASSPATH:$BATCH_LIB/antlr-2.7.6.jar"
    BATCH_CLASSPATH="$BATCH_CLASSPATH:$BATCH_LIB/aopalliance-1.0.jar"
    ...
}

setclasspath
launchbatch
```

How could I generate the content of the setclasspath function directly with maven so that it will inject all maven dependencies?

Note: I do not want to specify a directory containing all the jars in the classpath as the $BATCH_LIB directory is common to several batch applications.

So, this simple solution is not possible for me:

```
setclasspath() {
    BATCH_CLASSPATH=$BATCH_PROPERTIES/
    BATCH_CLASSPATH="$BATCH_CLASSPATH:$BATCH_LIB/"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to take a deep look at the [appassembler-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/) which generates such scripts.

It creates bash script but i would assume that it runes in many environments. You can find an example of how it works [here](https://github.com/khmarbaise/supose/tree/master/supose-assembly).